# Which are the best books I can refer for turbulent heat transfer and its computation?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, turbulence, convection

I am a graduate student. I wanted to do computation on heat transfer problem mainly heat convection. I am working on turbulent regime. Can you kindly suggest some good books so that I can get introduced and then use a few as references for my research from a physics perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of the best book for students about heat transfer at all is A Heat Transfer Textbook(Lienhard).  There you will find basic information about all types of heat transfer and it is available for free at MIT [web site](http://web.mit.edu/lienhard/www/ahttv131.pdf)

Comment: Please take a closer look at the resource-recommendation policy linked below the question and update your answer: What are the prerequesites? Can you detail a bit more what the book offers to the student?

Comment: Laurier, when I was in grad school at the University of Houston (1988), I took a heat transfer class from Dr. Lienhard.